# invalidate() not resulting in a call to onDraw()

Tags: java, android, graphics

When I call `invalidate()` rapidly (such as on response to a touch event), at some point `onDraw()` stops getting called. Here's some simple code that reproduces the problem:

```
public class TestView extends View {

public TestView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet as) {
    super(context, as);
}


public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    Log.d("tag", "drawing");
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("tag", "touchevent");
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

}
```

When you click and drag, initially you get both "touchevent" and "drawing" alternating in the log. After a while of rapidly moving across the screen, "drawing" disappears and the function `onDraw` is never called again.

I'm running things in the Android emulator targeting android 4.4.2

Comment: does onTouchEvent get called when you start seeing this problem?

Comment: Yeah; onTouchEvent is still called as it should be.

Comment: The only thing I would think of is to try to disable `View`'s drawing optimizations by calling `setWillNotDraw(false);` in constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that and forgot to include it in the code above. It didn't fix things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is a bug with the emulator, I've tried the exact same code with the Genymotion emulator and everything works perfectly. Haven't figured out how to fix it in the regular emulator except by not calling `invalidate()` more than once every 50 milliseconds or so.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the emulator. Real devices work fine. Is there any bug report about this somewhere?